# ImportError: cannot import name 'animation' from partially initialized module 'matplotlib'

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda, python-3.8

I'm facing the following erro:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0484cd13f94d> in <module>
----> 1 import matplotlib

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>
    105 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    106 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 107 from . import cbook, rcsetup
    108 from matplotlib.cbook import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning, sanitize_sequence
    109 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation  # deprecated

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py in <module>
     24 import numpy as np
     25 
---> 26 from matplotlib import animation, cbook
     27 from matplotlib.cbook import ls_mapper
     28 from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern

ImportError: cannot import name 'animation' from partially initialized module 'matplotlib'
```

I've removed matplotlib and then reinstalled it. I've also tried to use `pip install matplotlib --force-reinstall --user` command, but the error persists. The most curious is that matplotlib runs properly when I run Python in Windows Prompt Command, but not in Jupyter or Spider. I cant use admin privileges. Im running python 3.8.5 and matplotlib 3.4.2.